# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un predicado en ISO Prolog con un predicado como uno de los términos?

Tags: prolog

Necesito crear este predicado

```
menor(A,B,Comp,M)
```

que devuelva en `M` el menor entre `A` y `B` usando `Comp` como criterio de comparación. Comp es el nombre de un predicado que determina cuando un elemento es igual o menor que otro.

Por ejemplo, `menor(3,4,<,M)` devuelve `M=3`.

Comment: Debes poner qué tienes hecho hasta ahora. Aquí se resuelven dudas concretas.

Comment: no tengo ni puta idea de cómo hacerlo jaja, la pregunta es concisa de todas formas

Comment: Y si es posible, moderar el lenguaje.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar el predicado incorporado [call/*](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/call/3) que recibe como primer argumento un término que se puede llamar, y el resto de argumentos son los parámetros con los que llamar a dicho término.

```
?- X = <, call(X, 1, 2).
X = <.
?- X = >, call(X, 1, 2).
false.
```

En tu caso, el predicado que buscas sería algo así:

```
menor(A, B, Comp, A) :- call(Comp, A, B), !.
menor(_, B, _, B).
```

Cuando `A` es menor que `B` según el criterio `Comp`, el `call/3` de la primera cláusula tiene éxito y `!/0` corta la reevalaución del predicado `menor/4`. En cualquier otro caso, `call/3` falla y por lo tanto `B` es el menor (segunda cláusula).

Por ejemplo:

```
?- menor(1,2,<,X).
X = 1.
?- menor(1,2,>,X).
X = 2.
```